# what to do with rude edits

Tags: support

Upon reviewing suggested edits I have come across 'anonymous users' who try to post rude stuff/bad language, solely for the sake of spamming. Can I do something more than simply rejecting the edits? I mean, flag it or something to make it visible to the moderators higher up in the food chain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rejecting the edits as spam does trigger the anti-spam defense and will block edits from those sources if there are enough bad ones.